# Function that generate Code returns the same things

Tags: mysql, duplicates

There is a MySQL function in our web system to generate Code. The structure of the code is

```
district_cd(length:2) + date(length:8) + sequence no(length:5,start at 1).<like : ab2016090800001>
```

The sequence no was saved in table and will be updated (+1) when generate a new code.

But sometimes it returned two same codes and makes us fall in trouble. Here are the captures to replicate this problem, I will attach the DDL after this.

Step 1.Client1->change to manual commit then generate a code, but do not commit.

```
SET autocommit = 0;
select * from applies;
select * from sequence where apply_date = "2016-09-08";
select nextval("ab");
insert into applies (apply_id,apply_no,created,district_cd) values (2,"ab2016090800002","ab",now());
select * from sequence where apply_date = "2016-09-08";
```

Step2.Client2->change to manual commit then generate a code, stuck as Client1 locked

```
SET autocommit = 0;
select * from applies;
select * from sequence where apply_date = "2016-09-08";
insert into applies (apply_id,apply_no,created,district_cd) values (3,"ab20160908123456780","ab",now());
```

Step3.Client1->commit;

```
commit;
select * from sequence where apply_date = "2016-09-08";
```

Step4.Client2->code was generated and two records appeared in sequence table

```
select * from sequence where apply_date = "2016-09-08";
```

[capture of Step4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpCI7.png)

Step5.Client2->commit;one of the two records that appeared in sequence table was deleted.The codes generated are duplicated.

```
commit;
select * from sequence where apply_date = "2016-09-08";
select * from applies;
```

[capture of Step5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4xBW.png)

※DDL

**Table:applies   (apply_no:save the code)**

```
CREATE TABLE `applies` (
  `apply_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `apply_no` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `district_cd` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`apply_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Table:sequence (current_value:save current sequnce value)**

```
CREATE TABLE `sequence` (
  `district_cd` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `current_value` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `apply_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`district_cd`,`current_value`,`apply_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Function:currval->get current sequence value by district_cd**

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`usr`@`%` FUNCTION `currval`(d VARCHAR(3)) RETURNS int(11)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE value INTEGER;
    DECLARE needInitSequence INTEGER;
    DECLARE today DATE;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET needInitSequence = 1;

    SET value = 0;
    SET today = current_date();

    SELECT `current_value` INTO value
        FROM `sequence`
        WHERE `district_cd` = d AND `apply_date` = today limit 1;

    IF needInitSequence = 1 THEN
        INSERT INTO `sequence` (`district_cd`, `current_value`, `apply_date`) VALUES (d, value, today);
    END IF;

    RETURN value;
END
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

**Function:nextval->generate code by district_cd**

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`usr`@`%` FUNCTION `nextval`(d VARCHAR(3)) RETURNS varchar(16) CHARSET utf8
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE value INTEGER;
    SET value = currval(d);

    UPDATE `sequence`
        SET `current_value` = `current_value` + 1
        WHERE `district_cd` = d AND `apply_date` = current_date();

    RETURN concat(d, date_format(now(), '%Y%m%d'), LPAD(currval(d), 5, '0'));
END
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

**Triggers of applies->a business logic,if the length of apply_no is greater than 18,it will call the function:nextval to generate a new code**

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `convert_long_no` BEFORE INSERT ON `applies` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT LENGTH(NEW.apply_no)) >= 18) THEN
        SET NEW.apply_no = (SELECT nextval(NEW.district_cd));
    END IF;
END
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

My Questions:

1. Why did the function:nextval returns two same codes?
2. Why did two records appear in sequnce when update the record.

Comment: I couldn't follow everything you do, because you do a lot of steps for a simple thing (you could e.g just use a subselect and/or add the number as a column to query it from that table directly), but the reason seems to be your isolation level. Setting "autocommit = 0" doesn't (necessarily) mean other sessions can't read the data too. So they both might read the same data, one is updating, the other is stuck (depending on your isolation level), then updates with the previously read data. Tips: read about isolation levels (and maybe `select ... for update`), and simplify your process a lot.